# File interceptor in Wicket?

Tags: wicket-1.5

Do we have any functionality available in Apache Wicket for file uploads, where i can have different properties like file object,content Type,file name readily available.

Comment: Your question is very unclear to anyone unfamiliar with Struts 2. Maybe you could explain what you're looking for...

Comment: i was specifically looking for File interceptor like functionality thing in wicket,basically i wanted to know if                       1) I could configure different properties like size in some config file.                                                               2) I can directly access file properties as mentioned in example without writing any extra code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a FileUploadField, mark the form as multiplePart and when the form is submitted you can access the FileUpload which has properties getSize(), getContentType() and getClientFileName().

More info & example:
http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/FileUpload.html

http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-file-upload-example/